# Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout Array<Array<Any>>

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array : `var matrixOfMutableObjects: Array<Array<Any>>`
But when i try to check if the value on a certain position of the Array is a enum that i created the compiler complains: `Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout Array<Array<Any>>`

```
if(x < 0 || x > ROWS || y < 0 || y > COLS){
            return false;
        } else if (matrixOfMutableObjects[x][y] != enumObject.NOTHING){
            return false;
        }
```

Why cant i verify if the element in the position x,y of my Array is of the type enumObject.NOTHING that i created??

```
public enum enumObject {
    case NOTHING
    case Wall
}
```

Comment: unrelated, but you should use Swift's ranges for range checking: `if(!(0..<ROWS ~= x && 0..<COLS ~= y)) {`

Comment: Thanks! I'm still learning this details. Thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: No problem :) It just helps prevent common mistakes like mixing up `<` and `>` in a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching (used for matching cases in enum instances) and equality testing are two different things.

Also, an object wrapped in `Any` is only known to the compiler as `Any`, so you need to perform an attempted conversion to a given type prior to applying e.g. pattern matching vs cases of that type (say, if the type converted to is an `enum`).

E.g.:

```
public enum enumObject {
    case NOTHING
    case Wall
}

var matrixOfMutableObjects: Array<Array<Any>> = [
    [1, "two"],
    [enumObject.NOTHING, 4.2]
]

let x = 1
let y = 0
// no bounds checking in this simple example!
if case .some(.NOTHING) = matrixOfMutableObjects[x][y] as? enumObject {
    print("Is nothing!")
}
```

Or, using the `?` syntactic sugar:

```
// ...
if case .NOTHING? = matrixOfMutableObjects[x][y] as? enumObject {
    print("Is nothing!")
}
```

Note that the outer `.some(...)` pattern matching (or `?` sugar) checks that the attempted conversion of the element to `enumObject` is successful. If that is the case, an additional pattern matching of is performed for the wrapped object (which is then known to be of type `enumObject`) to a given `case` of `enumObject` (`.NOTHING`, specifically).

---

#### Curiosities of Swift: avoiding the explicit type conversion

As pointed out by @Hamish in a comment below, it seems that enum case pattern matching can actually perform the conditional type casting for you, meaning you needn't resort to the explicit casting and nested pattern matching above (`as?` and `.some(...)`/`?`, respectively), but can simply use pattern matching against the `NOTHING` case directly, given that you also supply the `enum` type:

```
if case enumObject.NOTHING = matrixOfMutableObjects[x][y] {
    print("Is nothing!")
}
```

---

Finally, note that the [Swift API Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) prescribes lowercase enum cases, so you might want to use the cases `nothing` and `wall`, rather than `NOTHING` and `Wall`, and additionally `CamelCase` name convention for types (so prefer `EnumObject` over `enumObject`).

Comment: Woah – the enum case pattern can do conditional type casting for you... `if case EnumObject.nothing = matrixOfMutableObjects[x][y] {...}` totally works (I can't seem to find any documentation on the behaviour though, which is odd).

Comment: I can only say, w00t! That's, ehm, surprising and kind of weird. Nice catch!

Comment: That kind of opens up quite a few neat solutions to somewhat weird `Any` questions that I've passed through in the past year (although I can naturally not find these questions right now :). Surely a thing I shall remember, cool stuff!

Comment: @Hamish when I think it over, it's quite logical that what you mentioned above works, as Swift:ers somewhat frequently `switch` over `Any` instances and test them again concrete types using `is`, or directly against explicitly type `enum` cases (which, I would assume, make use of the same conditional type casting behind the hood). I just never thought (or got into a scenario) where this is applied so straight-forwardly in an `if case` statement.

Comment: I guess it does make sense in the context of a `switch` where for example `switch matrixOfMutableObjects[x][y] { case EnumObject.nothing: ... }`, although it's nonetheless still quite a surprising implicit behaviour, as one might expect it to hold for arbitrary values such as `case "foo":`; but it doesn't as that's now an expression pattern, handled by `~=`. But it's certainly cool nonetheless – I'm not complaining :)

Comment: @Hamish shameless cross-QA-ping (targeted at generic collection specialist Hamish :), but do you know, on the top of your head, why I fail to use the `index(where:)` method for a `Slice` instance in the `Collection` extension mentioned [in my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42995063/4573247)? I assume I'm missing some constraint for the extension (`Collection where ...`), but I haven't been able to figure it out myself (`index(where:)` is accessible neatly if applying the extension to the concrete `Collection` `Array`, i.e. for an `ArraySlice`).

Comment: ... my own investigations only got me so far as believeing that `Slice` instances should inherit the [`index(where:)` implementation of `Collection`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CollectionAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L107), which is non-constrained. So one guess of mine is that I'm missing some constraint (/cast) to tell the extension that the `Base._Element` of the slice is the same as `Iterator.Element` of the collection.