# Swift: Map Array of Objects Alphabetically by Name(String) into Separate Letter Collections within a new Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have created a struct called Contact which represents a human contact where there are currently a few in an Array. They are already sorted alphabetically however I would like to sort them alphabetically by the name property which is a String BUT I don't just want to have them in order in a single array, I would like to split the objects out into different collections which is corresponded by the first letter of their name. eg. "A" contains 2 objects where a Contacts name begins with A, "B" for names like Bobby, Brad etc.. and so on and so forth.

```
let contactData:[Contact] = [
  Contact(id: 1, available: true, name: "Adam"),
  Contact(id: 2, available: true, name: "Adrian"),
  Contact(id: 3, available: true, name: "Balthazar"),
  Contact(id: 4, available: true, name: "Bobby")
]
```

I would like to create something like

```
let sectionTitles = ["A", "B"]
let sortedContactData = [
  [
    Contact(name: "Adam"),
    Contact(name: "Adrian")
  ],
  [
     Contact(name:"Balthazar")
     Contact(name:"Bobby")
  ]         
]
```

Or something similar...

The end result is that I would like to display them into a UITableView with the letters in Sections and the Objects into indexPath.rows much like how the Contacts app native to the iPhone does it. I am actually not sure whether this is the most ideal way to achieve this result so I welcome any challenges to this question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
let sortedContacts = contactData.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name }) // sort the Array first.
print(sortedContacts)

let groupedContacts = sortedContacts.reduce([[Contact]]()) {
    guard var last = $0.last else { return [[$1]] }
    var collection = $0
    if last.first!.name.characters.first == $1.name.characters.first {
        last += [$1]
        collection[collection.count - 1] = last
    } else {
        collection += [[$1]]
    }
    return collection
}
print(groupedContacts)
```

1. sort the list. O(nlogn) , where n is the number of items in the Array(contactData).
2. use `reduce` to iterate each contact
   in the list, then either add it to new group, or the last one. O(n), where n is the number of items in the Array(sortedContacts).

If you need to have a better printed information, you better make Contact conforms to protocol `CustomStringConvertible`

Answer (score 1):

#### Chunk up a collection based on a predicate

We could let ourselves be inspired by Github user [oisdk:s `chunk(n:)`](https://github.com/oisdk/SwiftSequence/blob/master/Sources/ChunkWindowSplit.swift#L17) method of collection, and modify this to chunk up a `Collection` instance based on a supplied `(Element, Element) -> Bool` predicate, used to decide whether a given element should be included in the same chunk as the preceeding one.

```
extension Collection {
    func chunk(by predicate: @escaping (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> [SubSequence] {
        var res: [SubSequence] = []
        var i = startIndex
        var k: Index
        while i != endIndex {
            k = endIndex
            var j = index(after: i)
            while j != endIndex {
                if !predicate(self[i], self[j]) {
                    k = j
                    break
                }
                formIndex(after: &j)
            }           
            res.append(self[i..<k])
            i = k
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

#### Applying this to your example

Example setup (where we, as you've stated, assume that the `contactData` array is already sorted).

```
struct Contact {
    let id: Int
    var available: Bool
    let name: String
}

let contactData: [Contact] = [
  Contact(id: 1, available: true, name: "Adam"),
  Contact(id: 2, available: true, name: "Adrian"),
  Contact(id: 3, available: true, name: "Balthazar"),
  Contact(id: 4, available: true, name: "Bobby")
]
```

Using the `chunk(by:)` method above to split the `contactData` array into chunks of `Contact` instances, based on the initial letter of their names:

```
let groupedContactData = contactData.chunk { 
    $0.name.characters.first.map { String($0) } ?? "" ==
        $1.name.characters.first.map { String($0) } ?? ""
}

for group in groupedContactData {
    print(group.map { $0.name })
} /* ["Adam", "Adrian"]
     ["Balthazar", "Bobby"] */
```

#### Improving the `chunk(by:)` method above

In my initial (non-compiling) version of `chunk(by:)` above, I wanted to make use of the `index(where:)` method [available to `Slice` instances](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/slice):

```
// does not compile!
extension Collection {
    func chunk(by predicate: @escaping (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> [SubSequence] {
        var res: [SubSequence] = []
        var i = startIndex
        var j = index(after: i)
        while i != endIndex {
            j = self[j..<endIndex]
                .index(where: { !predicate(self[i], $0) } ) ?? endIndex
            /*         ^^^^^ error: incorrect argument label in call
                                    (have 'where:', expected 'after:') */
            res.append(self[i..<j])
            i = j
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

But it seems as if it can not resolve this method correctly, probably due to a lacking constraint (`Collection where ...`) in the extension. Maybe someone can shed light on how to allow the stdlib-simplified extension above?

We may, however, implement this somewhat briefer extension if we apply it to `Array`, in which case `index(where:)` can be successfully called on the `ArraySlice` instance (`self[...]`):

```
// ok
extension Array {
    func chunk(by predicate: @escaping (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> [SubSequence] {
        var res: [SubSequence] = []
        var i = startIndex
        var j = index(after: i)
        while i != endIndex {
            j = self[j..<endIndex]
                .index(where: { !predicate(self[i], $0) } ) ?? endIndex
            res.append(self[i..<j])
            i = j
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with the extension is that the compiler is pretty limited in what it knows about the given `Collection`'s `SubSequence` – it only knows that it's a `Sequence`, but doesn't know that it should have the same element type (and in this case also be a `Collection` and have the same index type) as the main collection. This is due to the fact that we don't have `where` clauses for associated types ([but soon will do](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md), which will improve the situation considerably :) ).

Comment: The solution is to add the constraints `where SubSequence : Collection, SubSequence.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element, SubSequence.Index == Index` to let the compiler know that 1) You can use the `index(where:)` method on the subsequence 2) The subsequence's elements are the same as the main collections (so you can use the predicate) 3) The index returned is the same index type. Although it's worth noting that the subsequence having the same index *type* as the collection doesn't necessarily guarantee that subsequence index values correspond to the collection's index values

Comment: – this is guaranteed with slices, but AFAIK there's no way to constrain a collection extension so that the subsequence is a slice. Although that being said, I'm not aware of any cases where a collection's subsequence has the same index type, but not the same index values as the main collection – but it's still a corner case that I feel is worth mentioning.

Comment: Although even with the mentioned constraint, there's still a problem with the fact that you're calling `index(after: i)` in the main body of the method, which can crash for an empty collection – instead you can defer the initialisation of `j`, e.g `var j: Index` and then for the assignment do `j = self[index(after: i)..<endIndex].index(where: ...)` instead (to prevent an infinite loop upon the first element meeting the predicate). Using `index(after:)` there is now safe because we know `i` it isn't the `endIndex`.

Comment: @Hamish thanks for the detailed comments (given your thorough answer, I realized I should've probably posted this as an actual question: might post this at a later point, so you can cut in your comments as an answer), will read through after getting through the meeting-choked-friday, thanks!

Comment: Ah, ignore my earlier comments w.r.t the corner case of the subsequence sharing the same index type, but not the same values as the main collection – the documentation for the ranged subscript says "*The accessed slice uses the same indices for the same elements as the original collection uses.*", so it sound like it's a semantic requirement of `Collection`, therefore your implementation should be fine.

Comment: Oh, I also totally forgot to say that none of the closure function parameters need to be `@escaping` :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dictionary's init(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init)  like so:

```
    lazy var sectionDictionary: Dictionary<String, [Contact]> = {


        return Dictionary(grouping: contactData, by: {

            // assumes title is a non-empty string
            let name = $0.name
            let normalizedName = name.folding(options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive], locale: .current)
            let firstCharAsString = String(normalizedName.first!).uppercased()
            return firstCharAsString
        })
    }()
```

I spelled out the different transformation steps but you can combine them in a one-liner if you like.

This yields a dictionary with the section names as keys and arrays of objects as values.
From there you can easily extract the section array of arrays and you get your section names array for free:

```
    lazy var sectionTitles: [String] = {

        return self.sectionDictionary.keys.sorted()
    }()

    lazy var sections: Array<[String]> = {

        return self.sectionTitles.map { sectionDictionary[$0]! }
    }()
```

Please mind that I use some force unwrapping which you should `guard` from in production code.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no single-map way to do that, so the algorithm is:

```
var sectionedData: [String: [Contact]] = [:]
contactData.forEach {
    guard let firstLetter = $0.name.characters.first else {
        sectionedData["#"] = (sectionedData["#"] ?? []) + [$0]
        return
    }
    let firstLetterStr = String(firstLetter)
    sectionedData[firstLetterStr] = (sectionedData[firstLetterStr] ?? []) + [$0]
}

let sortedContactData = sectionedData.sorted(by: { $0.0.key < $0.1.key })
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for filtering and splitting a collection to smaller collections as many as given predicates.

e.g. given array of ints [1, 2, 3, 4] applying predicates: `odd`, `even` and `>3`,

result would be `[ [1, 3], [2, 4], [4] ]`

**Note:** The subsets can be repetitive depending on the given predicates. (I'm curious if this can be improved. `reduce` has complexity: O(n))

```
extension Collection {
    func filterParts(_ predicates: ((Element) -> Bool)...) -> [ [Element] ] {
        let empty = predicates.map { _ -> [Element] in return [] }
        let enumeratedPredicates = predicates.enumerated()
        return reduce(empty) { (result, element) in
            var result = result
            enumeratedPredicates.forEach { offset, predicate in
                if predicate(element) {
                    result[offset].append(element)
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    }
}
```